# My layout values are not updating

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gps

So I have `Track.java` with its layout that is just suppose to show me updated GPS coordinates with `myTextLat` and `myTextLong`. And a `MainActivity.java` that has a method `locationChanged` that spits out new GPS data as it becomes available, but for whatever reason my layout is not updating with the new data, despite being able to see new coordinate data coming out of `locationChanged` in the system out. I can statically set them by doing a settext in onCreateView, but for some reason they will not update through setMyCoords. Can someone help me figure out why the data, when available, is not being passed into my layout? Is there another, better, way to pass data from the activity to objects in a fragment so they are always updatedy? Thanks.

> MainActivity's locationChanged

```
 @Override
    public void locationChanged(double longitude, double latitude) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Longitude: " +longitude);
            System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
            Track f = new Track();
            f.setMyCoords(latitude,longitude);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
```

> Track.java

```
package "";

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Track extends Fragment {
    MiddleMan mCallBack;
    TextView myTextLat;
    TextView myTextLong;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallBack = (MiddleMan) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ReqestConnect");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.track_display, container, false);

        myTextLat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_lat);
        myTextLong = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_long);
        mCallBack.DisplayHome();

        return view;
    }

    public void setMyCoords(final double slat, final double slong) {
        myTextLat.setText(Double.toString(slat));
        myTextLong.setText(Double.toString(slong));
    }
}
```

This might also help. Each fragment replaces a framelayout in MainActivity when called. it looks like this.

```
@Override
     public void ShiftView(Object obj) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_framelayout, (Fragment) obj);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

With the actual call being something like.

```
Track f = new Track();
ShiftView(f);
```

**Conclusion**

With Joel Min's help I was able to come to the conclusion to my problem. I only have one activity but use several fragments to take on the role of having multiple activities, from the viewpoint of the user:

> activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#27b"
        android:layout_weight=".04">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_framelayout">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#1B5F96"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_status_title"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_status_title"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AD3333"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_status_value"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_status_value"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Framelayout eats the vast majority of the display, with ShiftView basically swapping in the fragment's layout by calling on the fragment class, as stated above. The problem? Shifting views is done by the onOptionsitemSelected method where each entry essentially looks like this:

```
if (id == R.id.action_track_display) {
            Track f = new Track();           
            ShiftView(f);
            return true;
```

Which has been fine for the project up to this point, however, Track.java needs to do something the other classes don't, it needs to receive and retain gps data regardless of where the user is in the app. My menu produces a new Track object, my locationChanged method produces a new Track object every time the location changes [which is a lot of objects], none of the objects are the same and none are connected to MainActivity.java in any way. The result, you get a crashless app that has a Track object's layout visible to the user that never updates and a series of background Track objects that exist for a fraction of a second, each containing one set of gps points. The fix, pretty simple:

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Track my_track;
    ...



 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_track_display) {
            if (my_track==null) {
                my_track = new Track();
            }
            ShiftView((my_track);
            return true;
        }
    ....

@Override
    public void locationChanged(final double longitude, final double latitude) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Main-Longitude: " +longitude);
            System.out.println("Main-Latitude: " + latitude);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                    
                    my_track.setMyCoords(latitude,longitude);
                }
            });
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each fragment replaces a framelayout in MainActivity when called

But you are calling `f.setMyCoords(latitude,longitude);` after the fragment has been created and returned to the main UI as it is (without setMyCoords applied). So move `f.setMyCoords(latitude,longitude);` from your locationChanged method to ShitView method. Of course then you will need to have global variables `tempLong` and `tempLat` to temporarily store the longitude and latitude values in locationChanged, and access them in ShiftView. Below is the modified code:

```
private double tempLong, tempLat; //declare it at class level

@Override
public void locationChanged(double longitude, double latitude) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Longitude: " +longitude);
        System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
        Track f = new Track();
        tempLong = longitude;
        tempLat = latitude;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
@Override
 public void ShiftView(Object obj) {
    (Fragment) obj.setMyCoords(tempLat, tempLong);
    //if above line causes error try the line below;
    //Track f = (Fragment) obj;
    //f.setMyCoords(tempLat, tempLong);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_framelayout, (Fragment) obj); 
    //ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_framelayout, f);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I cannot guarantee the above code would work because I don't have the full code. But basically you either need to set the longitude and latitude before the fragment transition in main activity occurs, or set a callback mechanism in your setMyCoords method so when it's called it calls back the main activity to update the textviews with new long and lat.

Comment: Is there a better way to pull fragments into a framelayout other than what I have been doing in shift, which is essentially to get a new one and ditch whatever was there before hand?

Comment: You can grab the current fragment in the framelayout with something like 'ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_fragment_id); ' and then grab your textviews with 'TextView tv = (TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);' then do tv.setText("your string");

Comment: I became very ill shortly after my last post and have been unable to get back to this until now. I believe this would work, but it would greatly alter ShiftView which is just a method setup to work with onOptionsItemSelected, basically showing you the layout of the selected java class. Effectively what I was doing was working, but each menu entry was effectly `JavaClass f = new JavaClass();  ShiftView(f); return true;` Since there is no saved object between the MainActivity and most classes this was fine, but track was to be constantly updated in the background. You led me to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are calling setText from NOT ui thread.
Consider calling it in UI thread using smth like this:

```
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myTextLat.setText(Double.toString(slat));
        myTextLong.setText(Double.toString(slong));

    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that, I tried it in Track and under locationChanged, both at once, nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any code blocking UI thread? Try adding logs before myTextLat.setText(Double.toString(slat)); call (which must be run using runOnUiThread as i mentioned before) and see if this code is reachable